# How to compare the 2 table and save into the another table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This is my Import table:

[image]

This is my Collection Table:
[image]

My problem is,
I am feeding "date" as input it should be compare that the two table having same type of data. it send the message as having same the data in table otherwise if doesn't same it should be save into the "collection" table.

My code is:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `collection` Left outer JOIN import on import.cdate != collection.collection_date WHERE collection_date="2019-07-11"")->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this :

```
SELECT * FROM `collection` Left outer JOIN import on import.cdate = collection.collection_date WHERE collection_date="2019-07-11" AND import.cdate != collection.collection_date
```

Comment: it shows an empty array,in both table having the data of that date

Comment: my question pick the data from two table for given "date" and compare the both data if they are same it should display a message "the data is same"  or save into the "collection" table

Comment: that's normal the return of the select is null because for "2019-07-11" you have the same date in the both tables, can you test with another rows or date whre you have not the same date

Comment: the same answer only came empty rows

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this query :

```
SELECT 
  a.dt,
  (
    CASE
      WHEN c.cdate IS NULL 
      THEN 'save this' 
      ELSE 'the data is same' 
    END
  ) AS reslt 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    '2019-08-07' dt) a 
  LEFT JOIN `collection` b 
    ON a.dt = b.collection_date 
  LEFT JOIN `import` AS c 
    ON b.collection_date = c.cdate 
    AND b.pcode = c.code
    AND b.pname = c.name
    AND b.rcode = c.rcode1
    AND b.rmaster = c.rmaster1
    AND b.collection_amt = c.camt
    AND b.loan_no = c.lno
    AND b.receive_amt = c.ramt
    AND b.loan_amt = c.lamt
    AND b.route_no = c.rno;
```

> In *"SELECT '2019-08-07' dt"* you need to pass it your input and here
>   i'm matching all the rows to get perfect match. If you need only date
>   match you can avoid all other rows matching conditions and you can
>   keep "*b.collection_date = c.cdate*" only.

***IMPORTANT: indexing columns makes query more faster.***